# Networking and the card reader stopped working when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, hardware

I just upgraded my lgz35 to Ubuntu 14.04. All the networking and the card reader stopped working. Is there any way to fix it since, I want internet back on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

For the networking, have a look at /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. I'm guessing that you also have a Broadcom network card. edit the blacklist.conf file as root and remove any lines starting with bcm. If there is a file in the same directory starting with blacklist-bc*, move it somewhere else for the time being. Upun rebooting, yor drivers will no longer be blacklisted.

Please note that this is based on the assumption that your cards are Broadcom chipset based. Although I've not heard of this problem occurring with Atheros chipsets, a similar series of changes using "ath" rather than "bcm" should fix the problem.